# Error while installing ubuntu 15.04, unable to install grub-efi-amd64-signed

Tags: grub2, package-management

I tried to install Ubuntu 15.04 in my HP lap which has windows 8 OS.

While installing, it showed an error that it was unable to install `grub-efi-amd64-signed` and it also mentioned that the above said package is very important for boot process. Please help me to resolve this issue.